# Travis-CI and Coveralls

Tags: travis-ci

I just cannot hook up the automatic update of coveralls.io to my Travis-CI build. All works fine if I execute the scripts on my machines. Here is the last message from the build log:

```
Submitting coverage to coveralls.io...
   Coverage submitted!
   Couldn't find a repository matching this job.
   'url'
   The command "python travis-ci/run.py" exited with 0.
```

Any hints or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Best, Philipp

Comment: I suggest asking this as a github issue, OR through Google Groups, Gitter, etc.

Comment: This is a bug about coveralls. a good place is github issues.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `TRAVIS`, `TRAVIS_JOB_ID` and `TRAVIS_BRANCH` environment variables are defined when calling `coveralls`.

If you're using Tox for example, an extra step is needed as described in the [coveralls-python readme](https://github.com/coagulant/coveralls-python#usage-tox--v20).

Answer (score 0):

This question is older, but the current problems show the same error. (And Google finds this too :-))

There were issues opened about it in [node-coveralls](https://github.com/nickmerwin/node-coveralls/issues/166) and [coveralls-public](https://github.com/lemurheavy/coveralls-public/issues/1264) (and [one more](https://github.com/lemurheavy/coveralls-public/issues/632)) repositories. It appeared, that [Coveralls got accidentally blocked by Travis](https://github.com/nickmerwin/node-coveralls/issues/166#issuecomment-465299938).

Although the problem was supposed to be fixed, as the comments on the second issue suggest, it occurred again. I myself could upload a new report neither from my machine, nor from Travis. I switched from Coveralls to [Codecov](https://codecov.io/).